# Como aumentar o período do horário do fullCalendar

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

Como deixa o período da hora do fullCalendar em quatro período de 15 mim cada. 
E como iniciar as linha dos horários através de um terminado horário. Por padrão o plug vem inicializado as 0:00  e final 23:00.

Outra duvida e como colori um determinado horário que não ficara disponível na agenda por exemplo horário de almoço;

Para mudar a cor de um determinado horário estou tentando dessa forma:

```
var calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
  defaultDate: '2014-11-10',
  defaultView: 'timeGridWeek',
  events: [
    {
      start: '2014-11-10T10:00:00',
      end: '2014-11-10T16:00:00',
      rendering: 'background'
    }
  ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Duração do slots**

Para dividir o período de uma hora em 4 slots de 15 minutos, utilize a propriedade `slotDuration`.

Exemplo: `slotDuration: '00:15:00',`

Link para [Documentação](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/slotDuration).

---

**Horário de Inicio do calendário**

Para definir o horário de inicio do calendário a propriedade é `minTime`.

Exemplo: `minTime: '08:00:00',`

Link para [documentação](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/minTime).

---

**Horário de termino do calendário**

Para definir o horário de final do calendário a propriedade é `maxTime`

Exemplo: `maxTime: '18:00:00',`

Link para [documentação](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/maxTime).

---

**Horário de trabalho**

Para definir o horário de trabalho e manter o horário fora do expediente com outra cor utilize a propriedade `businessHours`

Exemplo: businessHours:

```
[ // specify an array instead
  {
    daysOfWeek: [ 1, 2, 3 ], // Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday
    startTime: '08:00', // 8am
    endTime: '18:00' // 6pm
  },
  {
    daysOfWeek: [ 4, 5 ], // Thursday, Friday
    startTime: '10:00', // 10am
    endTime: '16:00' // 4pm
  }
]
```

Link para [documentação](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/businessHours).

---

**Alterar cor dos horários fora de expediente**

Ao adicionar a propriedade `businessHours` a `div` dos horários fora de expediente serão gerados com a `class='fc-nonbusiness'` e terão uma cor cinza claro `(#d7d7d7)`.

Para alterar a cor basta modificar o seu `css` adicionando algo como o exemplo a baixo:

```
.fc-nonbusiness {
   background: #fff
}
```

---

**Corrigir formatação no grid de horários**

Após colocar a propriedade `slotDuration` o grid de horários pode não exibir os minutos para horas fechadas(:00), por exemplo 07:00 fica exibindo 07.

Não encontrei na documentação uma propriedade pra configurar isso, resolvi efetuando o ajuste manual no evento `viewRender` do calendário, efetuando um for nos objetos e corrigindo os textos na propriedade.

Segue exemplo:

```
viewRender: function() {
    $('tr.fc-minor').each(function() { 
        const time = $(this).attr('data-time'); 
        const a = time.split(':'); 
        const seconds = a[0] + ":" + a[1];
        $(this).find('.fc-time').html(seconds);
    });
}
```

Comment: Como que tiro a exibição dos minutos do quadrão, quando coloquei  `slotDuration: '00:15:00'` ele exibe 7 e 7:30, também gostaria de colocar nesse formato 07h00 em vez de aparecer somente 7.

Comment: Vou editar a resposta adicionando como solucionar este "bug"....

Comment: mesmo com a função continua a exibir da mesma forma: 07 e os minutos ainda estão sendo apresentados.

Comment: Verifique se no seu html gerou com as mesmas class do exemplo que passei, e veja se não gerou erro no console.